# Favicon changed in google search after malicious code, but in browser tab didn't change

Tags: google-search-console, wordpress, favicon, malicious

The WordPress site had malicious code two months ago and favicon changed only in Google search results. An icon that appeared was never used so the picture is unknown to me. But the favicon that we use was showing in a browser tab and favicon checker.
The website was cleaned from that malicious code, the favicon was removed and set again in the root directory, the home page was requested for indexing in Google Console, and WordPress was reinstalled.
Time has passed and the icon didn't change in Google search.
Please if anyone has some advice or idea what to do, I would appreciate help.